# Python text file read/write optimization

Tags: python, io, text-files, read-write

I have been working on this file i/o and have made some progress reading through the site and i am wondering what other ways this can be optimized. I am parsing a test infile of 10GB/30MM lines and writing to an outfile the fields which results in aprog 1.4GB clean file. Initially, it took 40m to run this process and i have reduced it to around 30m. Anyone have any other ideas to reduce this in python. Long term i will be looking to write this in C++ - i just have to learn the language first. thanks in advance.

```
with open(fdir+"input.txt",'rb',(50*(1024*1024))) as r:
w=open(fdir+"output0.txt",'wb',50*(1024*1024)))
for i,l in enumerate(r):
    if l[42:44]=='25':
        # takes fixed width line into csv line of only a few cols
        wbun.append(','.join([
                                l[7:15],
                                l[26:35],
                                l[44:52],
                                l[53:57],
                                format(int(l[76:89])/100.0,'.02f'),
                                l[89:90],
                                format(int(l[90:103])/100.0,'.02f'),
                                l[193:201],
                                l[271:278]+'\n'
                            ]))
    # write about every 5MM lines
    if len(wbun)==wsize:
        w.writelines(wbun)
        wbun=[]
        print "i_count:",i
    # splits about every 4GB
    if (i+1)%fsplit==0:
        w.close()
        w=open(fdir+"output%d.txt"%(i/fsplit+1),'wb',50*(1024*1024)))
w.writelines(wbun)
w.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running it in Pypy (https://pypy.org), it will run without changes to your code, and probably faster.

Also, C++ might be an overkill, especially if you don't know it yet. Consider learning Go or D instead.

Comment: I'll have to see if I have the right privileges to install this. Interesting though, I didn't know there was an upgrade to CPython. Will check  back in this week to confirm. I do agree that this would make it faster though.

Comment: You can get Pypy as a portable binary, so no privileges are necessary: https://github.com/squeaky-pl/portable-pypy#portable-pypy-distribution-for-linux
Also, it's not an official upgrade, but it's an incredibly well-made drop-in alternative.

Comment: i am going to mark this as complete - i ended up converting this into Cython which reduced the time from 30m to 20m for a 10GB/30MM lines in the file. i will also look to see what the portable version of PyPy does, no doubt it will be fast - did not want to leave the question hanging. Thank you for your help!